# I'm trying to create a simple user input via Scanner so people can choose a shape as well as parameters for the shape for it to then be calculated

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, calculator, shapes

I'm currently in the process of learning Java and I have been given a task to re-write my program. My program at the moment consists of a method called: calculateArea() which is used to calculate 3 different shapes area (a Rectangle, Circle and a Square).

I now need it to accept user input to choose one of the three shapes, for it to accept user input for the parameters (length and width) and for it to then calculate it and after printing the correct result, to close the program.

I already created setters and getters for the different shapes and tested that everything works, what I struggle with is how to implement the Scanner to accept the different Shape inputs.

I tried a simple Scanner input for now like this:

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter shape to calculate: ");

String shape = keyboard.nextLine();
shape = String.valueOf(rectangle.calculateArea());
System.out.println("Your chosen shapes area is: " + shape);
```

Though this way, it always calculates Rectangles values as I'm directly calling the method on Rectangle. How would I need to re-write it, for it to take the shape + parameters and then print out the value of said input?

I'm still very new and I don't know how to tackle issues/research like this to find out the right answer, so I would appreciate pointers.

Comment: You should edit your calculateArea method and add a String parameter. Then add your 'shape' there. Now you are just return always the same thing (which we can't see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a class per shape like

```java
class Rectangle {
        private double height;
        private double width;

        public Rectangle(double height, double width) {
            this.height = height;
            this.width = width;
        }

        public double calculateArea() {
            return height * width;
        }
    }
```

and

```java
class Circle {
        private double radius;

        public Circle(double radius) {
            this.radius = radius;
        }

        public double calculateArea() {
            return radius * radius * 3.1415;
        }
    }
```

what you could do is depending on a value of `shape` `String` that you get from `keyboard` `Scanner` to instantiate a class corresponding to the shape and call its `calculateArea()` method, e.g.,

```java
        String shape = keyboard.next();
        if ("rectangle".equals(shape)) {
            System.out.println(new Rectangle(keyboard.nextDouble(), keyboard.nextDouble()).calculateArea());
        } else if ("circle".equals(shape)) {
            System.out.println(new Circle(keyboard.nextDouble()).calculateArea());
        } else {
            System.out.println("unknown shape, known shapes are rectangle and circle");
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This seems like a good solution. 

And yes, I do have separate classes for each shape + a class named Shape with the method calculateArea() which is then used to extend over to the other classes. 

I will try this out and play around with this a bit, to get a feel for the Scanner. Thanks again!